# Joining two tables but the join key is in a query string

Tags: php, mysql, sql, left-join

I want to join these two table but the join key of the second table is in a query string,

`page` table,

```
page_id     url
1           a
2           c
3           d
```

`system` table,

```
system_id       query
1               page_id=1&content=on&image=on
2               type=post&page_id=2&content=on
```

as you can see that `page_id` is part of the **query** string in `system` table.

so how can I join them like the standard joining table method below?

```
SELECT*
FROM page AS p

LEFT JOIN system AS s
ON p.page_id = s.page_id
```

**EDIT:**

I def can change the `system` table into something like this,

```
system_id       page_id    query
1               1           page_id=1&content=on&image=on
2               2           type=post&page_id=2&content=on
3               NULL        type=page
```

But the reason why I don't want to do this is that the `page_id` is no need for many certain records. I don't want make a column with too many `null`.

Comment: Can't you pre-process the system table with a 3rd column so that on insert you set the correct page_id. Then you get a clean join and you don't suffer performance issues.

Comment: Is there a chance to change the schema?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you wanted something like this (MSSQL!):

---

```
DECLARE @query VARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @Lenght INT  
DECLARE @PageID INT 

SET @query = '4kkhknmnkpage_id=231&content=on&image=on'
SET @Lenght = PATINDEX('%&%', substring(@query,PATINDEX('%page_id=%', @query),50)) - 9
SET @PageID = CAST(SUBSTRING(@query,PATINDEX('%page_id=%', @query) + 8,@Lenght) AS INT)

SELECT @PageID -- you can do as you please now :)
```

---

OR:

```
SELECT*
FROM page AS p
LEFT JOIN (SELECT CAST(SUBSTRING(query,PATINDEX('%page_id=%', query) + 8,(PATINDEX('%&%', substring(query,PATINDEX('%page_id=%', query),50)) - 9)) AS INT) AS page_id
                FROM system) AS s
ON p.page_id = s.page_id 

-- Do as you please again :)
```

---

**I guess what you really wanted was something like this (MYSQL!):**

---

```
SET @query := '4kkhknmnkpage_id=231&content=on&image=on';
SET @Lenght := POSITION('&' IN (SUBSTR(@query,POSITION('page_id=' IN @query),50))) - 9;
SET @PageID := CAST(SUBSTR(@query,POSITION('page_id=' IN @query) + 8,@Lenght) AS  SIGNED );

SELECT @PageID
```

---

**OR**

---

```
SELECT*
FROM page AS p
LEFT JOIN (SELECT CAST(SUBSTR(query,POSITION('page_id=' IN query) + 8,(POSITION('&' IN (SUBSTR(query,POSITION('page_id=' IN query),50))) - 9)) AS  SIGNED) AS pageID
           FROM system) AS s
ON p.page_id = s.pageID
```

Comment: thanks for this answer, but I get this error, `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INT) AS page_id FROM system LIMIT 0, 30' at line 3`

Comment: I think the problem comes from `PATINDEX` as I get this error if I simplify your query `#1305 - FUNCTION mydb.PATINDEX does not exist`

Answer (score 2):

I would definitely create columns for `page_id`,`content`, `image` and `type` (and get them indexed). Then the database would be much lighter and would work much faster.

Answer (score 1):

#### Joining two tables without the common field and data type, is fundamentally wrong IMO.

I will suggest that you extract the `page_id` and insert it in the database and use a normal join to accomplish what you are searching for.

SO making the columns like

```
+------------+-----------+---------+
| system_id  |  page_id  |  query  |
------------------------------------
```

Here is a snippet with which you are extract the page_id.

```
$query = 'page_id=1&content=on&image=on';
$queryParts = explode('&', $query);

$params = array();
foreach ($queryParts as $param) {
    $item = explode('=', $param);
    $params[$item[0]] = $item[1];
} 
$page_id = $parems['page_id'];
```

Then you can go on with the insert and use simple join statement to solve your problem in a proper way.

---

**Update:**

Since you are able to change the schema to a feasible one. You dont need to worry about some rows having empty rows on this.